# how to change the length of string

Tags: c++, string

When a string is created, whether the length of the string is constants?

How can I change the length of the string?

I only know that `s.length()` return the length of the string, but don't know how to change it.

thank you.

Comment: What does "changing" mean? Do you want to chop something off, or insert something? (You can do both of those.)

Comment: The formulation of your question is unclear. With what goal in mind do you want to change the length of the string?

Comment: Why do you want to change the length of string

Comment: Find [documentation on `std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and **read it**. You cannot expect to ask StackOverflow every time you have a really, really basic question about the tools you are using.

Comment: @ravi  "Why do you want to change the length of string". Indeed it is very suspicious that he has such seditious thoughts!:)

Answer (score 3):

> *"When a string is created, whether the length of the string is constants?"*

No, the `std::string` class is designed to manage the memory occupied by the underlying `char` array dynamically (and thus changing it's length).

> *"How can I change the length of the string ?"*

There are many ways, to change the `length()` value of a `std::string` instance. One for example is the [`std::string::resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) function.

Comment: smart answer...but irrelevant till OP justifies the reason for doing so.

Comment: @ravi There are plenty of reasons to change the length of a string. the OP doesn't have to _justify_ anything.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious What if OP wanted to change length by eliminating characters from the beginning of the strings. Does this take it into account...

Comment: @ravi I voted to close the question because of _"Unclear what you asking"_. If you think the question is unclear, downvote/flag/closevote or answer. You have enough rep to do so ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use method `resize` that is overloaded for class `std::string`

For example

```
std::string s( "Hello" );

s.resize( 10 );
```

In this case the string will be appended with zeroes ( '\0' ).
or

```
std::string s( "Hello" );

s.resize( 10, ' ' );
```

In this case the string is appended with blanks.

Also you can use method append. For example

```
std::string s( "Hello" );

s.append( 10 - s.size(), char() );
```

or

```
std::string s( "Hello" );

s.append( 10 - s.size(), ' ' );
```

These code snippets are equivalent to the previous code snippets.

Take into account that if you will create a constant string then indeed its length will be constant.:) For example

```
const std::string s( "Hello" );
```

The length of the string is 5.

If you mean character arrays then in C++ you may not change their lengths because they shall be constant expressions. Though some compilers have some language extensions.

In C you can use variable length arrays.